# Error: Graph container element not found

Tags: angularjs

Why am I getting an exception "Uncaught Error: Graph container element not found" when using morris.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: Put the javascript after the morris.js div

From this post from tiraeth: https://github.com/morrisjs/morris.js/issues/137